# How to assign values to dynamic const variable in C?

Tags: c

I got curious about dynamic `const` variable in C.

So, when I was testing there is a problem with assigning a value to it, while there is no problem with allocating `const` variable dynamically.

Yeah I am aware that we can use static `const` variables but it will be more memory efficient if we want to work with big `const struct`.

so here is a program that I had tested..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    const int *a = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    *a = 77;
    printf("value of a %d", a);
    return 0;
}
```

The error I am getting..

```
main.c:15:8: error: assignment of read-only location ‘*a’
   15 |     *a = 15;
      |        ^
```

So is there any way to do it?

Comment: Why is this tagged C++ if it's a C file containing C code?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel I think there not much difference here except cout and printf and headers..

Comment: What do you mean by "static dynamic memory"? Is it static or dynamic?

Comment: it is dynamic with ```static``` keyword.

Comment: In C++, that would be `const int* a = new int(77);` In C, I don't know of any syntax to allocate and initialize memory at the same time, so assigning the result of `malloc` to a pointer-to-const doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik this syntax new to me I didn't knew that before.. and Thanks

Comment: but how about in C?

Comment: If you want a C answer, then remove the C++ tag and references to C++ in the title.

Comment: Actually I also wanted to know in c++ too that why I have added , but I got it C++..

Comment: Sure I will change it..

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes I have changed it to C.

Comment: Any other change required for clearity then please let me know.

Comment: *"It's dynamic with `static` keyword"* - Except there is no `static` keyword in any of the posted code. [Please update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71097086/edit) with proper code, and *exactly* what your desired behavior of the allocated memory is. Is your intent that the dynamic-allocated memory be read-only (which would be utterly useless), or the pointer pointing to it be read-only? Both? Neither?

Comment: @WhozCraig hope  now it is more clear?

Comment: Why do you use const when you want to modify the data?

Comment: "more memory efficient " No. The initialize data has to be stored somewhere, so it is less efficient to dynamically allocate and copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `const` is largely to help programmers avoid modifying an object unintentionally. When you declare `a` with `const int *a`, then the type of `*a` is `const int`. In particular, it is `const` qualified, and this means it is not modifiable per C 2018 6.3.2.1 1:

> … A *modifiable lvalue* is an lvalue that does not have array type, does not have an incomplete type, does not have a const-qualified type,…

Using `*a` as the left operand of an assignment violates C 2018 6.5.16 2:

> An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.

Essentially, declaring `a` with `const int *a` says you **do not want** to modify `*a`.

If you want to dynamically allocate memory, assign it an initial value, and then use it as a `const` type, you can do this with two pointers:

```
int *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
if (!p)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error, unable to allocate memory.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
*p = 77;
const int *a = p;
```

Then `*p` is a modifiable lvalue you can use to change the memory, and `*a` is a non-modifiable lvalue you could pass to another routine with the `const` qualifier to help avoid inadvertent changes to the memory. (It is not an absolute guarantee; the C standard allows code to convert a `const int *` to an `int *` and use it to modify the memory, as long as it does not point to an object that was originally defined with `const`.)

You could further reduce the opportunity for accidentally modifying the memory by reducing the scope of `p`:

```
const int *a;
{
    int *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
    if (!p)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, unable to allocate memory.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    *p = 77;
    a = p;
}
// p is not in scope here, but a is.
printf("*a = %d.\n", *a);
```

However, then, when you pass the address to `free`, you need to use a cast to remove `const`, as in `free((void *) a);`.

Comment: I assume this is a typo: ".... says you do not want to modify `a`". It is perfectly fine to change `a` (changing where `a` points to). It is `*a` you can't change (modifying the content of the memory slot `a` points to).

Answer (score 0):

You can initialise the const object when you allocate it. Example:

```
auto ptr = std::make_unique<const int>(77);
```

Comment: The question was updated, it is asking about C.